# Report on job status by agent in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a bunch of on-prem agents and I want to create a report that lists the jobs per agent and their status.

There doesn't seem to be anything in the Pipeline Analytics Metadata that references the agent that the job was run on.

Is this data available anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the current job & status for an agent via the rest api:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

You can find the pool id via the the URL from the UI or make a separate call to:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=7.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=7.0)